# Specific Term for prejudice/prejudiced behaviour (racial, gender, etc...) that justifies itself by a prior history of prejudice?

Tags: politics, psychology, racism

If someone made the following, certainly problematic, statements:

"There is a higher risk (member of oppressed minority) will underperform at a job or task, since it is more likely they are traumatized or disenfranchised by prejudice and/or poor treatment they have suffered in the past."

"(Member of oppressed minority) cannot be trusted, since there is an above average likelihood they will harbor mistrust or resentment due to being treated poorly before."

Is there a specific term for this kind of thinking/prejudiced behaviour - which can easily lead to a factually racist or other anti-minority outcome, WITHOUT a need for the person making that kind of judgement to be themselves categorically racist or against the minority in question?

Comment: Have you considered "prejudice"?

Comment: plain prejudice to me would imply that the prejudiced person justifies it by what they think is INHERENT rather than INDUCED in the "victim"....

Comment: How could what might be "INDUCED in the "victim" matter, please? Plain prejudice does imply that the prejudiced person justifies it by what is thought to be INHERENT. That both Answers the Question and stands as a pretty-good definition of what prejudice is…

Comment: INHERENT = "person will behave in xyz way due to what they are", INDUCED = "person will behave in xyz way due to how we or others treated them"

Comment: Related: [a metaphor for people living up or down to their reputation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/566349/a-metaphor-for-people-living-up-or-down-to-their-reputation)

Answer (score 1):

OED:

> **institutional racism**  n. **discrimination or unequal treatment on the basis of membership of a particular racial or ethnic group (typically one that is a minority or marginalized), arising from systems, structures, or expectations that have become established within society or an institution.**
>
> 1967   S. Carmichael & C. V. Hamilton Black Power 4   *When..thousands more [black children] are destroyed and maimed physically, emotionally, and intellectually because of conditions of poverty and discrimination in the black community, that is a function of institutional racism... It is institutional racism that keeps black people locked in dilapidated slum tenements.*

There is also the slightly different

**Systemic racism** n. **discrimination or unequal treatment on the basis of membership of a particular racial or ethnic group (typically one that is a minority or marginalized), arising from systems, structures, or expectations that have become established within society or an institution.**

> 1968   L. P. Zimmer in M. Boyd Underground Church ii. 29   *I am pretty well aware of..my increasingly forceful abhorrence of war, police brutality, corrupt politics, systemic racism, and money-grubbing religious structures.*

and

**institutionalized racism** which suggests more a growth of racism within a body and which is considered acceptable by its members.

Answer (score 0):

This might be described as *self-fulfilling prophecy*, as "*self-fulfilling bias*", or as "*confirmation bias*". I regret that I cannot think of a shorter term or a single word. It will be interesting to read what others say.

*confirmation bias* may be slightly too strong for what you describe because it often related to underlying desire rather than casual behaviour.

[Psychology Today](https://www.psychologytoday.com/gb/blog/science-choice/201504/what-is-confirmation-bias): Once we have formed a view, we embrace information that confirms that view while ignoring, or rejecting, information that casts doubt on it. Confirmation bias suggests that we don’t perceive circumstances objectively.